# Regex matches in regex101 but not in TypeScript regex test

Tags: regex, typescript

I need a regex which matches numbers from 0.0 - 6.0, it should also match with comma like this 0,0 - 6,0 and last but not least it should match the numbers from 0-6.

I am new to regex's therefore don't mind if my regex is completely wrong.

My current regex is -> `/(^[0-5][.|,]\d$)|(^[6][.|,][0]$)|(^[0-6]$)/gms`

This matches every case in regex101 but not in my typescript code.

In the Code I am matching my string as follows:

```
/(^[0-5][.|,]\d$)|(^[6][.|,][0]$)|(^[0-6]$)/gms.test(stringToTest)
```

This matches 0-6 and 0.0-6.0 but not 0,0-6,0. How can I improve my regex, that it works as shown in regex101?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
^(?:[0-5](?:[.,][0-9])?|6(?:[.,]0)?)$
```

- `^` Start of line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[0-5]` match a digit 0-5
  - `(?:[.,][0-9])?` Optionally match a `.` or `,` followed by a digit 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `6` Match 6
  - `(?:[.,]0)?)` Optionally match a `.a.` or `,` followed by a 0
- `$` End of line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8MPhXD/1)

Note that you don't need the pipe in the character class `[.|,]`, it means matching the pipe char literally instead of OR. The `[6]` does not have to be between square brackets.

You don't need the `/s` flag as the pattern does note make use of a dot `.` that should also match a newline.

```
const regex = /^(?:[0-5](?:[.,][0-9])?|6(?:[.,]0)?)$/gm;
```